# How to share my iPod music in the network using iTunes 'share' feature?

Tags: windows, itunes, music, ipod

I was wondering if any of you know a straightforward way to share my iPod music in the networks by using the 'share' feature already included in iTunes for Windows.

What I've done so far is to add the hidden music files in the iPod to the library but it becomes a problem when adding a new song to the iPod because I need to add all the files again and the process is slow

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that the music files only exist on your iPod's hard drive and not your computer?

If so then doing what you mentioned (adding the music files on the iPod HDD to iTunes) will be the only way unless you transfer them to your computer's HDD.

To avoid having to re-add them every time, you could be diligent about only running iTunes when your iPod is connected to your computer. That way it'll never notice the HDD missing.